# Struggling with deploying Rails 3.1 app with Capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, capistrano

We have multiple applications that are currently being deployed using Ruby 1.8.6 with Capistrano.  I know, i know, we're working on the upgrade, but these at least deploy just fine.

We have a new application that is running on Ruby 1.8.7, Rails 3.1.11, and we're trying to get deployment going with Bundler and Capistrano.  Our applications are in Subversion, and we've always used :deploy_via=>:checkout so that's what i'm trying to use to start.

The behavior i'm seeing is not computing for me, and i've been searching and tweaking for a day or so now:

```
➜  bundle exec cap deploy
  triggering load callbacks
  * 2013-11-06 14:13:31 executing `deploy'
  * 2013-11-06 14:13:31 executing `deploy:update'
 ** transaction: start
  * 2013-11-06 14:13:31 executing `deploy:update_code'
    executing locally: "svn info https://svn-server.com/path/to/branch --username \"myusername\"--password \"mypassword\"--no-auth-cache  -rHEAD"
Authentication realm: <https://svn-server.com:443>
Password for 'myusername--password':
*** [deploy:update_code] rolling back
  * executing "rm -rf /path/to/deploy/dir/releases/20131106221344; true"
  servers: ["myserver.com"]
```

**What seems like the most important line to me:**

```
executing locally: "svn info https://svn-server.com/path/to/branch --username \"myusername\"--password \"mypassword\"--no-auth-cache  -rHEAD"
```

Questions:

- **Why does 'svn info' even need to be executed locally, when i'm deploying via checkout?**
- **It looks like i'm being prompted for a password because the username/password in the 'svn info' command is being seriously munged??**

I'm specifying those credentials in the normal way:

```
set :scm_username, 'myusername'
set :scm_password, 'mypassword'
```

Environment info (relevant gems only):

```
➜  ruby -v
ruby 1.8.7 (2013-06-27 patchlevel 374) [i686-darwin12.4.0]
➜  gem -v
1.8.25
➜  gem list --local

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

actionmailer (3.1.12, 3.1.11, 3.0.20)
actionpack (3.1.12, 3.1.11, 3.0.20)
activemodel (3.1.12, 3.1.11, 3.0.20)
activerecord (3.1.12, 3.1.11, 3.0.20)
activeresource (3.1.12, 3.1.11, 3.0.20)
activesupport (3.1.12, 3.1.11, 3.0.20)
bundler (1.3.5, 1.3.1)
capistrano (2.15.5, 2.14.2)
multi_json (1.8.2, 1.8.1, 1.7.9, 1.7.8, 1.7.7)
mysql (2.9.1)
net-scp (1.1.2, 1.1.0)
net-sftp (2.1.2, 2.1.1)
net-ssh (2.7.0, 2.6.8, 2.6.6)
net-ssh-gateway (1.2.0)
rack (1.3.10, 1.2.8)
rack-cache (1.2)
rack-mount (0.8.3, 0.6.14)
rack-ssl (1.3.3)
rack-test (0.6.2, 0.5.7)
rails (3.1.11, 3.0.20)
rails-console-tweaks (1.0.1, 1.0.0)
railties (3.1.12, 3.1.11, 3.0.20)
rake (10.1.0, 10.0.3)
rcov (1.0.0)
rdoc (4.0.1, 3.12.2)
rdoc-data (4.0.1, 3.12)
ruby-debug (0.10.4)
ruby-debug-base (0.10.4)
ruby-debug-ide (0.4.9)
rubygems-bundler (1.1.1)
rvm (1.11.3.6)
rvm-capistrano (1.5.1, 1.4.4, 1.4.1)
sprockets (2.0.4)
tzinfo (0.3.38, 0.3.37)
whenever (0.8.4)
wirb (1.0.2, 1.0.1)
wirble (0.1.3)
```

If there's more info i can post that would help, please let me know.
Any help or guidance would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try forcing `capistrano` version `2.15.4` - I heard there was svn bug in the latest version of the `2` branch

Comment: You're an angel!  BTW, i did try to do a search for what versions of the different components were ideal for my configuration, but didn't come across anything about the 'svn bug' that you'd heard about - guess i'm not in the right circles :-D.  Forcing 2.15.4 looks to have resolved the issue, on to the next ;-). Thanks so much!

Comment: it's part of this https://groups.google.com/d/msg/capistrano/nmMaqWR1z84/hdjAGIGbwdYJ - the 2.15.5 was supposed to be yanked but was not